# How to calculate sum of object keys in array - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

## Question

I am working with firebase and react native.

I have returned an array from my firebase database that looks like this.

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

Under each object I have returned a single item, "level:4".

So I have three objects containing 4,5,6. How do I sum these together?

Thanks!

Comment: loop over it array, read the property, add...

Comment: Hey gbland777. Welcome to StackOverflow. As you've probably noticed your question got some downvotes. One way to prevent that is to provide (in your question) the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With that we can check your code to see what you might be doing wrong (or need clarification on), instead of trying to backtrace from your description. It's a more efficient for way for people to help; and the easier you make it for us, the more likely you are to get help. :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Either a simple loop

```js
var a = [{level:1},{level:2},{level:3},{level:4}],
        total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        total += a[i].level;
    }
console.log('total', total)
```

or reduce

```js
var a = [{level:1},{level:2},{level:3},{level:4}]
console.log(a.reduce( function(cnt,o){ return cnt + o.level; }, 0))
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use Javascript's reduce function. This is basically the same as @epascarello answer but in ES6 syntax.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
const arr = [{level:2},{level:4},{level:5}]; 

const total = arr.reduce((prev,next) => prev + next.level,0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to iterate over your array and sum your elements.

Let us suppose your array is `var foo = [object, object, object]`
Each `object` has this structure, `{ level : 4 }`

Write code like this:

```
var sum = 0;
foo.forEach(function(obj){
  sum += obj.level;
});
```

`sum` will store the sum

Answer (score 1):

This code will calculate the sum of an array.  First, declare one variable; this variable's name will be `sum`. `sum` contains the total's sum. Second, declare a `numbers` variable of type `Array`. This variable will contain digits.

Then we start a loop (for) operation, in which we assign to the `sum` variable the value of `(sum= sum+i);`.
Then we show in `(document.write)` the numbers and sum.

```
var summa = 0 , i ;
var numbers= [1,2,3,4,5];
for(i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++){
    summa=summa+i;
} 
document.write(numbers , ": bu reqemlerin cemi " ,"=" , summa);
```

Comment: sorry I am new stackoverflow and I do not know which part of the code is written   So I wrote it with the narration

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried accessing the object in the array and calling the property?

```
var array = [object, object, object];
var sum = array[0].level + array[1].level + array[2].level;
```