# Get SUM of value in Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get sum of the values in array. With this code when I `console.log(this.totalCount)` I only get like this [image].

How to get sum of all the values?

**CODE**

```
return this.http
      .post('/media', reqBody)
      .pipe(
        map((res:IStatisticReponse) => res.data)
      ).subscribe(res => {
        this.items = res.map((r: any, i: number) => {
          r.color = this.colors[i]
          return r;
        });

        this.legendProgress = this.items.map(item => {
          return { label: item.label, color: item.color };
        });
        this.totalCount = this.items.map((item)=> item.mediaShare);
        console.log(this.totalCount)

        this.isLoading = false;
      });
```

Comment: *The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.* so you code must be `this.totalCount.length` even I not sure why you are using map with empty value

Comment: @OnurGelmez when I add `this.items.length` I got error `(property) Array<any>.length: number
Gets or sets the length of the array. This is a number one higher than the highest element defined in an array.

This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Number' has no call signatures.ts(2349)`

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(this.items)`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale when `console.log(totalCount)` it result like this `Array(3) [ "2656", "1987", "1071" ]`

Comment: You want the result count as - `3` in above case?

Comment: I want total all value... not total length

Comment: I guess, you should say, you need `sum` of those value

Comment: what do you mean by total all value? Is it all objects from that list not only `mediaShare`?

Comment: example: totalCount = 2656 + 1987 + 1071

Comment: `this.items.forEach(function(value, index, arry){
 this.totalCount += parseInt(value.mediaShare);
});`

Comment: Explore `reduce` e.g. `const arrSum = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate sum of object keys in array - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402442/how-to-calculate-sum-of-object-keys-in-array-javascript)

Comment: @Rohit.007.. Yes You are true..

Comment: @PrashantPimpale.. No.. It no answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current implementation you basically iterate over all items within the `items` array and return the objects `mediaShare` property.

```
this.totalCount = this.items.map((item)=> item.mediaShare); // => ["123", "345", ...]
```

What you actually want to do is to get the sum of all these values.
Considering the values inside `totalCount` are now a collection of `strings` that seem to hold a numeric value, you can do the following:

```
this.totalCount = this.items.map((item)=> Number.parseInt(item.mediaShare)).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0); // Or `parseFloat`, if your values might be of type float
```

Read up on [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to learn how it behaves.

Comment: Your code only display like this `265619871071 ` not sum of the value

Comment: I want it like this ` totalCount = 2656 + 1987 + 1071 `

Comment: Which is exactly what I gave you. I added another edit, maybe you checked the code prior to it. Please test it again with the latest solution provided.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let totalVal;
for(let i = 0; i < this.totalCount.length; i++) {
  totalVal = totalVal + parseInt(this.totalCount[i]);
}
```